# While running the rspec it shows does not implement( allow_any_instance_of )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rubygems

My rspec line

```
allow_any_instance_of(School).to receive(:admission).and_return(:body)
```

I have my admission method in my `lib/school.rb`
module School

```
def self.admission()
```

like this, but when i run the rspec it throws error like

```
Failure/Error: allow_any_instance_of(School).to receive(:admission),and_return(:body)
       School does not implement #admission
```

Answer (score 5):

`admission` is a class method in this example (note the `self.` in front of it). That means to allow any *instance* to receive that method doesn't make sense.

You have two options:

1. Keep it a class method but change the expectation to `allow(School).to receive(:admission)...` or
2. make `admission` and instance method by removing the `self.`

It depends on your application what approach makes more sense.